# Setting interpreter in Virtualenvwrapper

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenvwrapper

I've been using virtualenvwrapper for a while in OSX Mavericks. 
I have python 2.x and 3.x installed via homebrew. Creating environments for python 2 is not a problem. But now I want to create environments with python 3, so according to the [documentation](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html#python-interpreter-virtualenv-and-path) I can set the variable VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON to the full path of the interpreter to choose the interpreter:

```
# VIRTUALENVWRAPPER
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3
export WORKON_HOME="$HOME/.virtualenvs"
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Python_projects
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

So I did, but when I open my terminal it yells at me:

```
/usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.4: Error while finding spec for 
'virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader' (<class 'ImportError'>: No module
named 'virtualenvwrapper')
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization    
hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.4 and    
that PATH is set properly.
```

I checked that directory, and virtualenvwrapper nor virtualenv are installed there. So how do I install these packages for python 3?

These packages weren't installed, so I installed them with:

```
$ pip3 install install virtualenvwrapper
$ pip3 install install virtualenvwrapper
```

Now the problem seems to be another one:

```
$ mkvirtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python3 test

File /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/ssl.py", line 97, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/javi/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_ssl.so, 2): Symbol not found: _SSLv2_method
  Referenced from: /Users/javi/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_ssl.so
  Expected in: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
 in /Users/javi/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_ssl.so
```

**Solution:**

After doing:

```
$ brew uninstall --force python
$ brew uninstall --force python3
```

And installing them again:

```
$ brew install python
$ brew install python3
```

and fixing some broken links:

```
$ brew linkapps python
$ brew linkapps python3
```

The problems seem gone. By default virtualenvwrapper puts a python3 executable in my new environments, thanks to the line in my **.bashrc**:

`export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3`

And also, when I need to create an environment with python 2.X inside, I can do:

`$ mkvirtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python test4`

And it runs fine.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have OS X to test this on, but it looks like you have installed virtualenv (and virtualenvwrapper) to python2.7 site-packages directory ([or the homebrew site-packages directory](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Homebrew-and-Python.md#virtualenv)), and not to python3.4.

When running:
    source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
it's saying

> check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
>   VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.4

I installed this on ubuntu recently and used pip-3.4 to install virtualenv to python3.4 site-packages.

**EDIT:** this [python3 osx guide](http://blog.manbolo.com/2013/02/04/how-to-install-python-3-and-pydev-on-osx#2) says that pip3 comes with homebrews python3 package. Installing virtualenvwrapper with pip3 will fix your issue.

**NOTE:** If you install two virtualenvwrappers (via pip and then pip3), I do not know if they will play nice together.

Comment: The initial idea wasn't to install 2 different virtualenvwrappers, but just create virtual environments with the python 3 interpreter in them:
``mkvirtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python3 test``
, but it didn't work.

Comment: Don't set the `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON` to python 3 then, it'll default to python2, `source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh` will work, and you can create a virtualenv using python3 (as you say) with `mkvirtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python3 test`.

Comment: Thanks Craig. To be honest right now I prefer to do:
1. Set ``VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON`` to Python3.
2. Use the ``--python`` option for the cases I need Python2.
But hey, I can always go back and do it the other way around.

Comment: Yep, same difference. I posted that before I saw you had updated your question! FYI, virtualenvwrapper installs to the pythonX/site-packages directory determined by the version of pip you use. virtualenvwrapper  also puts files in some common places like: `/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`. By installing using pip (python2.x), then install using pip3 you're overwriting these files with the python3.x version. I don't know if it'll cause any issues, but that's why it's defaulting to python3.x.

Comment: @Bobbywankenoby, should this be the accepted answer? If so, click the check mark, top left.